# How to set up zend CLI in Mac

Tags: zend-framework

I was googling and looking for how to set up zend cli on Mac Leopard. Can you please suggest?
I am using XAMPP 1.7.4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [**Zend_Tool_Framework Programmer's Reference Guide**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html). However installation for mac is not described there.

---

You can use the **PEAR package installer** to get Zend_Tool running on your mac.

**Fetching and installing:**

1.

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.zfcampus.org
sudo pear install zfcampus/zf-devel
```

2.

```
sudo svn co http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/incubator/library/Zend/Tool/ $HOME/Cos/Zend/Tool
sudo rsync -r --exclude=.svn $HOME/Cos/Zend/Tool /opt/local/lib/php/Zend
```

**Link into system:**

3.

```
sudo svn co http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/incubator/bin $HOME/Cos/Zend/bin
sudo ln $HOME/Cos/Zend/bin/zf.sh /opt/local/bin/zf
sudo ln $HOME/Cos/Zend/bin/zf.php /opt/local/bin/zf.php
```

**Check version:**

```
zf show version
```

From: http://raphaelstolt.blogspot.com/2009/01/installing-zendtool-on-mac-os-x.html

---

**Subversion repository:**  http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/incubator/bin/

Another resource on zend developer zone: [**Using Zend_Tool to start up your ZF Project**](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3811)

Comment: svn: URL 'http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/incubator/library/Zend/Tool' doesn't exist. 
there is the problem actually with this link